# Spring Pagination from API

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, pagination

I have a Spring Boot project with Java. In the frontend I just use HTML, Bootstrap and Thymeleaf. There I created a searchbar, which I connected to a search controller. The data which are searched come from a private API.

Now I want to display the found results not with a scrollbar but on multiple pages. For this I have also chosen a Bootstrap template and integrated it. (View)

But now I have to implement the backend, the model and the controller. And there is my problem: I am still quite new in Java Spring and therefore looking for a tutorial or an explanation how I have to implement this. I only find tutorials where the data comes from a database and not from an API.  In my API the data for paging looks like this:

[image: pagination_in_api]

I don't want a pre-chewed solution here, just an explanation and maybe an example, since as I said I can't find an example for this to follow. I don't have the slightest idea how to implement the controller to control the pagination so that when I click on the buttons "First Page", "Next Page", "Last Page" it jumps to them.

Does anyone have an example and an explanation how I can do it on my own?

Looking forward to your answers

To solve the problem on my own I already searched for tutorials, went through Udemy course on Spring, asked ChatGPT.

Answer (score 1):

The solution you need will depend how complex your table is i.e. do you have filtering and sorting?
From the example you showed only serverside pagination is needed without any filtering and sorting.

I would use Pageable with in built Spring Data JPA methods such as `findAll()` in your repository.

What I would do is first create a controller to request the data.

```
   @GetMapping("/data")
    public Page<Data> getDataWithPagination(
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int page,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") int size) {
        return yourService.findPaginatedData(PageRequest.of(page, size));
    }
```

`PageRequest.of(page, size))` is an instance of `Pageable` and here you can define your current page and how big you want each page to be. If you want to include sorting in your pagination, you would also add it here.

Next create your repository

```
public interface YourRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Data, Long> {
    Page<Data> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

And then call this `findAll()` method from your service.

```
@Service
public class YourService {

    @Autowired
    private YourRepository yourRepository; 

    public Page<Data> findPaginatedData(Pageable pageable) {
        return yourRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }
}
```

And that's all you need to get started. If you want to go more complex, I would recommend looking into passing specifications into your `findAll()` method and do some filtering via criteria builder.